# DatePicker day colors WPF 4

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I have the following style for the text block in the dictionary

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0 "/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

after setting this in the resource dictionary, all the text block i have used in my project have foreground color to white which I have set, now the problem is that the datepicker control when open only shows the selected date, as I have set the foreground color of white for the text block in the above style the date picker control dates are not showing. Please help me as soon as possible as I am stuck in this problem :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use additional style for your DatePicker:

```
<DatePicker>
        <DatePicker.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Style>
        </DatePicker.Resources>
    </DatePicker>
```